# Stop Visual studio Auto-selecting files in Pending Changes after checkin with TFS

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs

I use the Pending Changes window in Visual Studio 2010 to manage my files and to checkin with TFS.

My problem is that I will often be working on something and have files checked out then go onto something else, and then something else etc.... I have a lot of files checked out at once.

When I do a checkin, even if its just 1 file visual studio automatically checks the checkbox next to all other files so I have to go through and uncheck the files I dont want for my next checkin.

Is there any way to turn this feature off?

Thanks

Comment: Which source control plugin are you using? VSS? AnkhSVN? TFS?

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that, its TFS

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I find it better to not mix changes of different things. You could use TFS shelves to park your work, while working on something else. Then nothing gets mixed.

Comment: I'm going to +1 the shelveset idea - that's one of the great things about shelving!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't think you can turn of this feature. To better control this behaviour you have a few options:

1. Select the folder in which you have the files that you want to check-in and right-click for the menu and choose from there for Check-in pending changes. That will select only the files within the folder/subfolders or project that you selected from the solution explorer.
2. You can use a trick to deselect all files marked for check-in in the pending changes window, by selecting one file, press CTRL-A and deselect a file.

Hope that these tips will give you a smoother check-in experience. Also take a note at the comment by Lars Truijens about not mixing changes. It will be very hard to separate these checkins at not break the build at some time.

Comment: Thanks, your second trick made my day!  Working with almost 100 files and this was really pissing me off!

Comment: Another shortcut similar to the "selecting one file, press CTRL-A and deselect a file." is to do CTRL-A and then space, which will deselect all the files. Make sure you have the "filter by solution" checked to prevent other check-out files from showing in the list of pending changes :)